# Как парсить страницу, которая загружена в WebView? Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, парсер, xamarin, webview, anglesharp

Есть страница (не моя и без API) с которой надо взять данные. 
Пример такой страницы

https://warthunder.ru/ru/community/userinfo/?nick=Keofox

Нужные данные находятся в таких блоках:

```
                        <ul class="profile-stat__list-sb">
                        <li class="profile-stat__list-item">СБ</li>
                        <li class="profile-stat__list-item">93</li>
                        <li class="profile-stat__list-item">64</li>
                        <li class="profile-stat__list-item">5</li>
```

Ранее парсер работал через AngleSharp, но недавно добавили защиту DDoS protection by Cloudflare. 
Соответственно парсер не работает, трюки с задержкой, паралельной загрузкой в webview успеха не дали.

Единственное возможное решение (на мой взгляд) это вытащить HTML код с уже загруженной страницы в WebView (в WebView страница проходит проверку cloudflare и загружается без проблем). 
Видел подобные примеры на Джава, но интерпритировать под C# не удалось.
Как можно вытащить из WebView HTML код и использовать его?

Comment: Cloudflare - это довольно простая антиддос защита, которая просто обходится. Несколько лет назад мы со знакомым решили обойти ее, в итоге получили [это](https://pastebin.com/gapnxkQw), не уверен в текущей работе, да и код был дико набросан на коленке, но думаю суть, если надо будет, то поймете. Ну а так, уже довольно давно есть [эта библиотека](https://github.com/elcattivo/CloudFlareUtilities), которая позволяет в более удобном формате все это обойти и получить нужные данные. Взял код, который там предложен, вставил вашу ссылку и получил все нужные данные, ну а дальше ваш любимый AngleSharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за полезный совет @EvgeniyZ

Надо установить через nuGet библиотеку https://github.com/elcattivo/CloudFlareUtilities

Итоговый код для AngleSharp:

```
    try
    {
        ClearanceHandler handler = new ClearanceHandler
        {
            MaxRetries = 2 
        };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        string source = await client.GetStringAsync("https://warthunder.ru/ru/community/userinfo/?nick=Keofox");
        var parser = new HtmlParser(); 
        document = parser.ParseDocument(source);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is CloudFlareClearanceException)
    {
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is TaskCanceledException)
    {
    }
```